# Encoding Uncompressed video

Tags: video, conversion, encoding, mpeg4

I'd like to encode uncompressed video into compressed avi or mpeg4. Was wondering what program I should look at getting to do such a task. Videos are between 3 and 20 minutes long, and range anywhere from 1.3 to 10 GBs in uncompressed .avi form (fraps).

Comment: For which operating system and which format you mean with "uncompressed video"? AVI is a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) is a very nice command line tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) is a great free tool for this job

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org) is yet another free tool to do this.  It might be easier to answer these questions if you asked more specifically. Do you want a graphical tool?  Command line?  Batch operation?  Windows?  Linux?  Mac?

FFMPEG is all of those except graphical, given simple scripting for batch operation.

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of [Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/) on Win systems

> Format Factory is a multifunctional
>   media converter. Provides functions
>   below:
>
> - All to MP4/3GP/MPG/AVI/WMV/FLV/SWF.
> - All to MP3/WMA/AMR/OGG/AAC/WAV.
> - All to JPG/BMP/PNG/TIF/ICO/GIF/TGA.
> - Rip DVD to video file , Rip Music CD to audio file.
> - MP4 files support
> - iPod/iPhone/PSP/BlackBerry format.
> - Supports RMVB,Watermark, AV Mux.
>
> Format Factory's Feature:
>
> 1. support converting all popular video,audio,picture formats to
>      others.
> 2. Repair damaged video and audio file.
> 3. Reducing Multimedia file size.
> 4. Support iphone,ipod multimedia file formats.
> 5. Picture converting supports Zoom,Rotate/Flip,tags.
> 6. DVD Ripper.
> 7. Supports 50 languages
>
> OS requirements: All 32 windows OS

And yes, it runs on Server 2008 R2 so 64-Bit should not be an issue (8 core i7 server)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not intimidated by a complicated interface and fine-grained control, [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

[Quicktime 7 Pro](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/) does that. It is available on Mac OS X and Windows but not on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) on Ubuntu Linux to convert AVIs to MP4s. It reduces the file size by about 90% and the quality is OK. I use it for all my Youtube uploads.

Here's the command I use. Replace `MVI_0963` (referenced twice) with the name of your video file.

```
ffmpeg -i MVI_0963.AVI -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec libfaac -ab 128kb -s 640x480 -b 1200kb -mbd rd -flags +4mv+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -pass 1/2 -r 25 mvi_0963.mp4
```